# Pig how to assign name to columns?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a csv file which have hundreds of columns, when I load the file into Pig, I dont want to assign each column like

```
A = load 'path/to/file' as (a,b,c,d,e......)
```

Since I'll filter a lot of them at the second step:

```
B = foreach A generate $0,$2,....;
```

But here, can I assign a name and type to each column of B? something like

```
B = foreach A generate $0,$2,... AS (a:int,b:int,c:float)
```

I tried the above code but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify them between each comma.

`B = foreach A generate $0 as a, $2 as b,...`

Note that it just assumes the type that it is already.

Comment: thanks, this works! But can I use sth like: B = foreach A generate (int)$0 as a, (float)$2 as b... to cast the type?